# Cannot send email "Send As" for my own email address

Tags: exchange

The SBS/Exchange account `foo` has several email addresses in the account properties:

- `office@email.xyz` -> main address
- `foo@email.xyz`
- `office@bar.xyz`

**The situation:** The account holder of `foo` can send emails only as `office@email.xyz`. When he tries to send emails as `foo@email.xyz` or `office@bar.xyz` then the email is rejected because the permission "Send As" has not been granted.

**My question:** Where can I set this permission for the last 2 emails - they **have not been created as Users/Email accounts**. They are only assigned in the `foo` account properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After consulting a Microsoft Exchange Administrator he told me that this is not possible.

If I want to use the **Send As** feature I have to add these email addresses as a separate Exchange mailboxes.